# How to hide scrollbar in <select>

Tags: google-chrome

I have the problem of hiding vertical scrollbar in  tag.

This is my code:

```
<select size="3" style="-webkit-appearance: listbox; height:150px; width:200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <option>abc</option>
  <option>def</option>
  <option>ght</option>
</select>
```

I have tried to use `overflow: hidden\auto` or setting `<select size="20">` or greater, it doesn't help me.

Is it possbile somehow hide this scrollbar in Chrome?

NB! No scrollbar in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using CSS3

```css
.conatainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid grey 1px;
}
.conatainer select {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="conatainer">
  <select name="year" size="3">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>def</option>
    <option>ght</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

or you can use

## [Webkit Scrollbar Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<div class="scroll">
<select size="3" style="-webkit-appearance: listbox; height:150px; width:200px; align-items: flex-start;">
  <option>abc</option>
  <option>def</option>
  <option>ght</option>
</select>
</div>
<style>
 .scroll { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; border:solid grey 1px; }
 .scroll select { padding:10px; margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px; }
</style>
```